# Browsing to .ASHX files on Windows Phone 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7

We have a whole bunch of WML pages that are served out using ASHX files and we've had no problems with them. However, someone has just got a Windows 7 Phone and when they browse to one of these pages they get:

```
Can't download file!
Windows Phone doesn't support .ashx files
```

Is there some IIS configuration that we need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The phone actually doesn't care about the extension.  It sounds like it's actually a problem with the mobile data provider.

You might want to check this out:

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7/thread/5b96aa40-f5f6-4123-8854-f666c822c4a6

In particular pay attention to: "Actually - all resolved now. I contatcted my mobile data provide and they knew what the issue was - they lifted a website restriction setting that had defaulted to. All in ordre now." (sic)

Comment: Thanks, I'll get the user with the Windows 7 file to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.ashx` to `.aspx` and override response.

Comment: I feared that. There are a lot of these pages and it will take a lot of work. Another reason not to go with Windows Phone for our users, I guess.